# I have mentioned flex value to 0.5 but it is not working

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have written following code but my flex under 'titleContainer' is not working.

```
export const Focus = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>What would you like to focus on?</Text>
        <TextInput />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#43840',
  },
  titleContainer: {
    flex: 0.5,
    padding: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#559974',
  },
  title: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 15,
  },
});
```

Please see the screen shot. The green background should cover half of the screen.
[image]

Its resolved now!
Actually this component was getting displayed conditionally. There was an issue with that condition. I have fixed that and everything worked.

Comment: what you want is that titleContainer occupy 50% height of container?

Comment: yes! I want that.

Comment: you need to make your parent container a {display: 'flex'} to use flex property in child tags.

Answer (score 0):

[Flex](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#flex) in RN only take interger value

In case you want titleContainer take 50% size of container by using flex, This is how you can achieve that.

You need another view the take the same flex value with titleContainer, so titleContainer and that dump view will take 50% size of parent view each

```
export const Focus = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>What would you like to focus on?</Text>
        <TextInput />
      </View>
      <View style={{flex: 1}} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#43840',
  },
  titleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#559974',
  },
  title: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 15,
  },
});
```

Comment: There is No Effect

Comment: @Developer did you add a dump view below titleContainer

Comment: Actually this component was getting displayed conditionally. There was an issue with that condition. I have fixed that and everything worked. I will delete the question shortly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use flex property on child tag your parent tag needs to have a **display: "flex"** property on it.

```
container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#43840',
  },
```